# php echo from mysql table contains text pictures and may contain [img] tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making userlist from mybb to our concrete5 website and I want users signature below his username.

Signature can be plain text, may contain links, images and images between [img] tag.
I already handled the plain image part. How do I need to change that print line to get everything to work?

Here are examples from mysql:

```
1. [img]http://image[/img]

2. [url=http://link][img]http://image[/img][/url]

3. Some user entered text
[url=http://link][img]http://image[/img][/url]
[url=http://link][img]http://image[/img][/url]

4. Some user entered text

5. http://image

6. [i]"Some user entered text"[/i]
```

Here is the code that prints at the moment username and img

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
print $row['username'] . '<br />'  . "<img src='" . $row['signature'] . "' />" . '<br     />'. '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will need to parse bbcode yourself, but this is a known task and there's plenty cookbooks around. The basics are that for every bbcode pattern you need its proper replacement.

In IMG's case:

```
$urlmatch = "([a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+)";
$img_pattern = "/\[img\]".$urlmatch."\[\/img\]/is";
$img_replacement = "<img src=\"$1\" />";
```

Every pattern that matches the $img_pattern should be converted to $img_replacement using preg_replace

```
$htmlsignature = preg_replace($img_pattern, $img_replacement, $row['signature']);
```

You should collect all bbcode you can have and run this preg_replace secuentially until you have gone through all possible patterns.

Credits to [Forrst example](http://forrst.com/posts/Simple_PHP_BBCode_Parser-N0z) with has helped me in the past.